# ASP.Net MVC Custom Route Handler with MemCached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a CMS written in ASP.NET MVC.  I have written a custom route handler that looks at the incoming path and determines where to route it (i.e. custom redirect,category page, product page, etc).  The current routes are stored in the cache on a memcached server.  Everything works great until we get high loads on the server.  I then either get errors retrieving from the cache or even 404 errors at times.  Also running a report that takes 5-10 seconds causes the whole server to hang

1. Should I be using a custom route handler to even begin with?
2. Is this not all being done asynchronously?

   ```
   public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)

   {
       var _lock = new Object();
       MvcHandler handler = null;
       var path = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToLower().RemoveOutsideSlashes();
       var qs = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;


       List<Cache.RouteItem> items;

       lock (_lock)
       {
           var cache = new CacheManager();
           items = cache.Routes;
       }

       if (!hasPermanentRedirect(path, qs, items, ref requestContext))
       {
           // check for categories first
           handler = checkForCategory(path, items, ref requestContext);

           // check for product
           if (handler == null) handler = checkForProduct(path, items, ref requestContext);

           // check for webpage
           if (handler == null) handler = checkForWebPage(path, items, ref requestContext);
       }

       if (handler != null) return handler;

       return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
   }
   ```

Comment: Am I understand right, that you write your own `HttpHandler` instead of using `RouteConfig` in MVC stack?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

- I would run profiler and see where is the most time spent. This will help you to understand where is the bottleneck in your code
- I would do your CacheManager class as static class, so you don't
  instantiate new CacheManager for each request.
- I would make checkForCategory, checkForProduct, and checkForWebPage
  methods async, so your code doesn't hold request threads, so you can
  handle more requests